# How to perform Prewitt Edge Detection using openCV in android studio?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, android

I am creating an Android application using OpenCV to compare image similarities to detect products anomalies. I already tried Canny, Sobel and Prewitt operators in Python and Prewitt gave me the best results in my case, since the product contains multiple objects. Now I need to make that in Android using OpenCV for Android, but I can't find any documents using the Prewitt edge detector on Android.

I tried the Canny and Sobel edge detectors on Android but the results are dissapointing.
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
This is the result from Prewitt operator in Python

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9fa7.png

And this is the result from Canny operator in Python

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1zSz.png

So as you can notice, Prewitt is more accurate in my case.

Edit 2:
I made some changes in my java code and I'll link the new output and code down below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KImeX.png

```
    @Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    //rgbImage = inputFrame.rgba();

   // return findLargestRectangle(rgbImage);

    mat = inputFrame.rgba();
    Mat mRgbaT = mat.t();
    Core.flip(mat.t(), mRgbaT, 1);
    Imgproc.resize(mRgbaT, mRgbaT, mat.size());
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgbaT, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.equalizeHist(gray, gray);
    //Imgproc.threshold(gray, gray, 127.5, 255.0, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
    Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(gray, gray, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 40);
   // Imgproc.Canny(gray, cannyImg, 50, 80);
   // Imgproc.Canny(gray, cannyImg, 50, 200, 3, false);


    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(gray, gray, new Size(5, 5), 5);
    final Point anchor = new Point(-1, -1);
    final int iterations = 2;
    Imgproc.erode(gray, cannyImg, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(3,3)), anchor, iterations);
   // Imgproc.dilate(gray, cannyImg, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(3,3)), anchor, iterations);
    Imgproc.Canny(gray, cannyImg, 50, 200, 3, false);
    return cannyImg;

}
```

Then I just removed the GaussianBlur and here is the result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8HN7.png

Comment: Maybe you need to further tweak the parameters to Canny. I cannot believe the results would be worse than those for the Prewitt operator.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for your quick answer. Please take a look at the edit.

Comment: That doesn't look like Canny at all. In any case, Canny has at least 3 parameters that you can tweak: the scale, and two thresholds. Play around with those a bit. The differences between Prewitt and Sobel is that Sobel uses a (ever so slightly) more sophisticated smoothing, the smoothing used in the Prewitt operator can cause harmful artifacts. Canny is a more complicated thing, it computes the gradient magnitude like you can do with these two other operators, but then adds non-maximum suppression and hysteresis thresholding. Consequently, the output is a binary mask.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I am already trying to play a little bit with Canny high and low threshold. Can you help me get the same result as Prewitt operator using Canny or Sobel ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, because I don't know what you've done so far. I know you're estimating the gradient magnitude using the Prewitt kernels. I don't know what you did with Sobel so far. OpenCV's `Sobel` function outputs an estimate of the derivative, you need to combine two derivatives to get the gradient magnitude. Did you do that? And Canny will not yield the same results, as I said before, it outputs a binary mask. This could be beneficial or not depending on what the application is.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Please take a look at my last edit and tell me what you think is wrong with the code ?

Comment: What’s wrong is that you’re applying Canny on a binarized image. Don’t threshold, just apply Canny on the grey-value image directly.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you Sir. I will try that and give you my feedback.